# Do I need to restart IIS after a configuration change?

Tags: iis-6, snmp, service

In IIS 6.0 Manager, I increased the size of message to 51200KB and restarted SNMP.  However, a mail of 25MB is still bouncing.

Do I need to restart IIS?  This is a production machine, so I have to go through change processes to do so.

Comment: You have to restart the IIS service, yes.

Comment: thanks, time to spend 20 minutes filling out a change request for a 1 minute change

Answer (score 0):

IIS6 reads the configuration settings up startup, so it must be restarted once most configuration settings are changed for them to take effect.